# Prove that OLS estimators under Heteroscedasticity is inefficient

Tags: econometrics, heteroscedasticity

How can I prove that OLS estimators under Heteroscedasticity is inefficient? Will comparing with OLS estimators under Homoscedasticity suffice? But how will I do that? Can anyone help asap?

Comment: Welcome to CV, Munif.  Have you reviewed the posts that [concern this topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=heteros*+efficie*)? Likely you will find all your questions already answered in them.  If not, come back and edit this post to indicate more specifically where you need help.